# How do I install Bash completions for my Haskell package's executable?

Tags: haskell, command-line-interface, cabal, bash-completion

The Haskell package `optparse-applicative` [provides instructions](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/wiki/Bash-Completion) for creating a bash completion script for an executable, and then suggests that this

> should be shipped with the program and copied to the appropriate directory usually (`/etc/bash_completion.d/`) during installation.

I wold like to ship and install this script with my package, along wit the executable. How do I instruct Cabal (in my .cabal) to

1. include the bash completion script along with my package, and
2. copy the script to `/etc/bash_completion.d/`?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think that Cabal can install files under `/etc`. To write there, one would need root permissions, and Cabal is usually run by non-root users. Also, adding system-wide configuration files should be done using the OS package manager like `apt`, installing a package, so that they can be tracked. Cabal can however specify that the distribution should carry `data-files`, so that those files should also be installed along the program in some directory. The user then has to copy/link to them.

Comment: @chi So best practice is to just instruct the user to do 2 themselves. What's the best way to accomplish 1?

Comment: I am not experienced enough to provide a real suggestion about Cabal best practices. I'd try to use `data-files:` for 1, even though there might be better ways.

Comment: Cabal is installing stuff into `~/.local/`. It is possible to include bash completion instruction into `~/.local/share`, and cabal could do that. Any ideas about how this could be done?